# GridView item overlaps when scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I have a problem with overlapping items in GridView. They are dynamically loaded by Universal Image Loader and problem is when some of them are not square. 
There is no problem when scrolling up to down:
[image]

There is a spacing. But when scrolling down to up:

[image]

As you can see, items overlaps here.

How can I fix it? Here is my Fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingProgressListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;

import java.util.List;


public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = WhatsHotFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private TopPodcastsAdapter adapter = null;
    private GridView podcastsGridView = null;
    private ITunesPodcastService iTunesPodcastService = new ITunesPodcastService();
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


    public WhatsHotFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whats_hot_fragment, container, false);
        podcastsGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.podcastsGridView);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
//                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();

        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.whats_hot);

        updateTopPodcasts();

        return rootView;
    }


    private void updateTopPodcasts() {
        new DownloadTopPodcastsTask().execute();
    }


    public class DownloadTopPodcastsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Podcast>> {

        @Override
        protected List<Podcast> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            List<String> podcastIds = iTunesPodcastService.getTopPodcastsIds();
            List<Podcast> podcasts = iTunesPodcastService.getPodcastsForIds(podcastIds);
            return podcasts;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Podcast> podcasts) {
            adapter = new TopPodcastsAdapter(getActivity(), podcasts);
            podcastsGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView podcastPrimaryGenreView;
        ImageView podcastImageView;
        TextView podcastTitleView;
        TextView podcastArtistView;
    }

    public class TopPodcastsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private List<Podcast> podcasts;

        public TopPodcastsAdapter(Context context, List<Podcast> podcasts) {
            this.context = context;
            this.podcasts = podcasts;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return podcasts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcast_card_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                assert view != null;
                holder.podcastPrimaryGenreView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.podcastCardPrimaryGenre);
                holder.podcastImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.podcastCardImage);
                holder.podcastTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.podcastCardTitle);
                holder.podcastTitleView.setSelected(true);
                holder.podcastArtistView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.podcastCardArtist);
                holder.podcastArtistView.setSelected(true);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            holder.podcastPrimaryGenreView.setText(this.podcasts.get(position).getPrimaryGenreName().toUpperCase());
            holder.podcastTitleView.setText(this.podcasts.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.podcastArtistView.setText(this.podcasts.get(position).getArtistName());

            imageLoader.displayImage(this.podcasts.get(position).getArtworkUrl600(), holder.podcastImageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                        }
                    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                        }
                    }
            );

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/podcastsGridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:background="@color/grid_background"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dip"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dip"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

And here is my item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/podcastCard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card_redborder"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/podcastCardPrimaryGenre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        style="@style/CardTextSecondary"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/podcastCardImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/podcastCardTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        style="@style/CardTextPrimary"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/podcastCardArtist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        style="@style/CardTextSecondary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help.

Comment: adjustViewBounds="true" tells your application that you want to keep the resolution, which is likely causing your image to be scaled differently than you are expecting. Try removing that, it may fix the overlapping, but will likely throw off your image resolutions. It will at least pinpoint what is causing the overlap.